# can't able to load the networkimage and data from api - flutter

Tags: flutter, api, compiler-errors, flutter-image

I got this error from image.dart while run the app.

the error hit on this line :

> throw error; (inside the assert)

And i got this error message on my console

> Image provider: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0) Image key:
> NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> I/flutter ( 6157): Error: 503
>
> i want to load the image and the data from api without getting error.
> i attached the source code images.

Error screenshot:

[image: error image]

Api Data Call screenshot:
[image: api data call]

Fetch Data Method screenshot:

[image: Fetch Data Method]

Comment: Check the URL of the image and the API endpoint to make sure they are correct and accessible.